# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')

Tags: discord.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  partials: [
    'MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'USER
  '],
  ws: { intents: Discord.Intents.all } 
})
```

---

El error que me da
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.